# Fatal error with Stripe Class 'Stripe\Stripe' not found

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments

I'm trying to implement Stripe Checkout into my website. In local the api work normal but in host I get the error :

> Class 'Stripe\Stripe' not found

**Note:** In my host I don't have SSH. And I added files manually with FTP.

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_XXXXXX");
   $token = $request->stripeToken;
   $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create([
   'email' => $client->email,
   'source'  => $token,
]);
```

Comment: did you install cashier package on your server ?

Comment: explain more  i dont install package  usin command line ssh in my server but i add all files vendor and config usi ftp

Comment: To use Stripe class you have to install laravel's package called cashier. Then you can use this class.

Comment: i install stripe package  in local work fine !! i have a problem with ssh in ms server i can't  run composer  commands in server

Comment: @AfrazAhmad Cashier makes working with Stripe easier, but it's certainly not **required**.

Comment: Are the vendor files definitely being uploaded?

Comment: If you can't run Composer on your server, try uploading the Stripe library manually (over FTP) and including it in your code. Also, you'll want to ensure your server uses at least PHP 5.4 or later https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php#manual-installation

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned you have installed Stripe library manually and uploaded on server.
To use this library include init file.

```
require_once('/path/to/stripe-php/init.php');
```

ON next step set Api key, Make sure to use test api key for testing.

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey( "sk_test_XXXXXX");
```

Make sure to download latest stripe library from [Githut repo](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/releases)

Answer (score 1):

As i have seen mentioned in the comments:

Stripe needs to be installed using (preferably) composer.

This can be done with the command: `composer require stripe` after having SSHed into the right directory.

You then need to include the `vendor/autoload.php` that is generated by composer.

In your case where you cant run composer do the following:
Download stripe`s latest release manually from the github page: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/releases

Then you need to include the `init.php` file found in the downloaded `stripe-php` directory like this `require_once('/path/to/stripe-php/init.php');`

Ensure you are running at least PHP 5.4 (Note! This version has reached its end of life. Upgrade if possible to PHP 7.2). You also need the PHP extensions `curl`, `json` and `mbstring`.

After having used `require_once('/path/to/stripe-php/init.php');` in the file the stripe code will be running in you can then set your API key using `\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_XXXXXX");` and then run your code like f.ex: `$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create([
   'email' => $client->email,
   'source'  => $token,
]);`
`

Answer (score 1):

Please use stripe library with the below code to resolve the error

```
$stripe_obj = new Stripe();
$stripe = $stripe_obj->setApiKey(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));
```